# Wagtail - Possible to rename an item in a streamfield in a migration?

Tags: python, wagtail

I've changed the name of an item in a StreamField from

```
tiles = StreamField(
    [
        ('items', StructBlock([
                ('icon', ImageChooserBlock()),
                ('text', CharBlock()),
            ])
         ),
    ], blank=True)
```

To

```
tiles = StreamField(
    [
        ('info', StructBlock([
                ('icon', ImageChooserBlock()),
                ('text', CharBlock()),
            ])
         ),
     ], blank=True)
```

Any idea how I can create a migration to rename the field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streamfield data is stored as JSON, as a list of items with 'type' and 'value' properties. To apply the field name change to all of your pages, you should be able to create an empty migration (or add it to an existing one), then add the following function or something similar to your migration file, then run it:

```
// other imports

import json

def convert_streamfield_name(apps, schema_editor):
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias

    MyPageModel = apps.get_model('myapp', 'MyPageModel')
    pages = MyPageModel.objects.using(db_alias).all()
    for page in pages:
        revised_stream_data = []
        stream_data = page.tiles.stream_data

        for data in stream_data:
            if data.get('type') == 'items':
                value = data.get('value')
                revised_stream_data.append({
                    'type': 'info'
                    'value': value
                })
            else:
                revised_stream_data.append(data)

        raw_json = json.dumps(revised_stream_data)
        page.tiles = raw_json
        page.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [...]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(convert_streamfield_name),
        ...
    ]
```

Comment: Awesome, cheers.   I guess I should really write the reverse migration too, but obvious how to do it once you know it one direction.